# github pages displaying the same repo accross all pages

Tags: html, reactjs, github, iframe, github-pages

I tried to upload a profile page to my `github.io/profile/portfolio` so that prospective employers would always land on the page no matter what they typed in the URL.

I made it with React. One of the features of my site is that when you click a button, an `iframe` loads with my other site inside of the site you are currently on. I did this so that users could browse all my works without having to leave the profile site.

The functionality is working fine but when it loads other sites from `github.io` it loads the profile again instead of the site i'm trying to show. When I go to the site directly it also shows the profile now instead of the site even though there are no changes to the repo of any kind. This bug also doesn't manifest itself every time (using Chrome).

How can I get my github pages to display their proper sites again?